# Как правильно сделать sql запрос на множественное where and?

Tags: sql

Всем привет, изучаю sql и столкнулся с задачей. Есть запрос

```
SELECT * FROM employees WHERE department IN ('sales', 'marketing');
```

Этот запрос вернет все строки из таблицы `employees`, где значение столбца `department` равно `sales` или `marketing`.

А как составить запрос таким образом, что бы запрос вернул все строки, где значение столбца не `или`,а конкретно `и`. Где значение столбца `department` равно `sales` и`marketing`.

Таких `и` может быть 5 или 10, в общем множественное `where and` не вариант)

Comment: Такой запрос вернет 0 строк, т.к. в столбце,  в одной строчке не может быть одновременно sales и marketing

Comment: по своему определению таких строк быть не может, пустое множество не доходя до выполнения запроса.

Comment: Как несколько значений записываются в одном столбце? Через запятую: `'sales, marketing'` или как-то ещё?

Comment: Да, забыл дописать.  'sales', 'marketing' будут подзапросом из другой таблички

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос, поместите всю необходимую информацию в него. Не пишите в комментариях.